# Uninitialized bytes error in Valgrind

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm new to C, and I'm doing some exercises with Valgrind.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int ints[10];
    char myString[50]; 

    for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        ints[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    printf("''string'' is %lu characters long\n", strlen(myString));
    strcpy(myString, "This is a medium sized string");
    printf("''string'' is %lu characters long\n", strlen(myString));

    return 0;
}
```

My Valgrind output:

```
==5425== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==5425==    at 0x260E9A: write$NOCANCEL (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x17E5E8: __sflush (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x180CAA: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x18B191: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x1AF2DA: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x1AF6AF: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x186B29: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x18496F: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x100000E73: main (test.c:15)
==5425==  Address 0x10001236e is 14 bytes inside a block of size 4,096 alloc'd
==5425==    at 0x6DEB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.9.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5425==    by 0x181855: __smakebuf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x196217: __swsetup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x1AF158: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x1AF6AF: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x186B29: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x18496F: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5425==    by 0x100000E73: main (test.c:15)
==5425==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5425==    at 0x100000DF0: main (test.c:6)
```

I'm thinking that the error is due to the fact that `myString` is "empty" when I make my first `printf` call, however, I'm unsure on how to resolve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking that the error is due to the fact that myString is "empty"

Not really. `myString` is not empty, it's uninitialized, the content of it is undefined , using `strlen(myString)` is thus illegal.

You can initialize it to an empty string like this:

```
char myString[50] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The string `myString` is not initialized when you make `strlen` call here:

```
printf("''string'' is %lu characters long\n", strlen(myString));
```

When `strlen` function goes through `myString` in search of `'\0'`, it reads uninitialized data. This is what is triggering the error in valgrind.

To fix this problem, add initialization:

```
char myString[50] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not true to say that `myString` is empty, it has *some* content. It's just that the content is arbitrary.

That means it may *not* have a zero byte somewhere in there to terminate the string, so calling `printf` or `strlen` on it is *not* a good idea, as it may run off the end of the buffer and cause problems.

You can make it work simply by ensuring it's a valid string, such as with:

```
*myString = '\0';
```